# Создание объекта класса описаного в массиве из Class<?>

Tags: java, ооп, generics

Можно ли в Java 8 создать объект от класса `Class<?>`?

Что-то вроде :

```
Number n = new Float.class;
```

Answer (score 10):

Да, [можно](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/ctorInstance.html). Существуют два метода для этого: [`Constructor.newInstance()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance-java.lang.Object...-) и [`Class.newInstance()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance--). Первый предпочтительней, так как:

- `Class.newInstance()` может вызывать только конструктор без аргументов, а `Constructor.newInstance()` может вызывать как конструктор с аргументами, так и без них.
- Если конструктор выбросит исключение, то метод `Class.newInstance()` пробросит его дальше, независимо от того, проверяемое оно или нет. Метод `Constructor.newInstance()` обёртывает любое исключение в `InvocationTargetException`.
- С помощью метода `Class.newInstance()` не получится создать объект с приватным конструктором, а с помощью метода `Constructor.newInstance()` в некоторых случаях может получиться.

Таким образом, если бы у класса `Float` был бы конструктор без аргументов, то можно было бы использовать второй метод:

```
// работает только для классов с конструктором без аргументов
Float instance = Float.class.newInstance();
```

Но у `Float` нет конструктора без аргументов, поэтому используем первый метод. Получить экземпляр класса `Constructor` можно с помощью метода [`getConstructor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor-java.lang.Class...-), который принимает классы параметров конструктора. Например, у `Float` есть конструктор, принимающий `double`:

```
Constructor<Float> constructor = Float.class.getConstructor(double.class);
Float instance = constructor.newInstance(7.77);
```

Answer (score 7):

```
Class<?> cls = Float.class;
Constructor<?> constructor = cls.getConstructor(Double.TYPE);
Number instance = (Number) constructor.newInstance(3.14);
```